# Not updating user's role after Stripe customer.subscription.created event in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, stripe-payments, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm creating a Wordpress Plugin to handle different Paid Membership levels for my website.
I've managed to create a subscription with Stripe and on my Stripe Dashboard I get a "200 OK" response. The event customer.subscription.created is triggered successfully.
If the user has chosen a 5€/month subscription, he will get access to some specific posts on my website. I need to change their role from "subscriber" to "self learner" for that to happen, but when I check the Database, the user role hasn't been updated, even if the subscription has been successfully created.
This is my code:

```
function stripe_webhook() {

    if(isset($_GET['webhook-listener']) && $_GET['webhook-listener'] == 'stripe') {

        if (is_user_logged_in()){ 

            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

            require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'stripe-library/init.php');

            global $italianglot_options;
            $italianglot_options = get_option('italianglot_settings');

            if(isset($italianglot_options['test_mode']) && $italianglot_options['test_mode']) { 
                $publishable = $italianglot_options['test_publishable_key'];
            } else {
                $publishable = $italianglot_options['live_publishable_key'];
            }

            if(isset($italianglot_options['test_mode']) && $italianglot_options['test_mode']) { 
                $secret_key = $italianglot_options['test_secret_key']; 
            } else {
                $secret_key = $italianglot_options['live_secret_key'];
            }

            if(isset($italianglot_options['test_mode']) && $italianglot_options['test_mode']) { 
                $price_selflearner_monthly = $italianglot_options['test_selflearner_monthly']; 
            } else {
                $price_selflearner_monthly = $italianglot_options['live_selflearner_monthly'];
            }

            if(isset($italianglot_options['test_mode']) && $italianglot_options['test_mode']) { 
                $price_selflearner_yearly = $italianglot_options['test_selflearner_yearly']; 
            } else {
                $price_selflearner_yearly = $italianglot_options['live_selflearner_yearly'];
            }

            Stripe::setApiKey($secret_key);

            if(isset($italianglot_options['test_mode']) && $italianglot_options['test_mode']) { 
                $endpoint_secret = $italianglot_options['test_endpoint_secret'];
            }else{
                $endpoint_secret = $italianglot_options['live_endpoint_secret'];
            }

            $body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
            $event_json = null;
            $event_json = json_decode($body);

            if(isset($event_json->id)) {
                try {

                    $event_id = $event_json->id;
                    $event = Stripe_Event::retrieve($event_id);
                    
                    switch ($event->type) {
                        case 'customer.subscription.trial_will_end':
                            $subscription = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\Subscription
                            // Occurs three days before a subscription's trial period is scheduled to end, or when a trial is ended immediately (using trial_end=now).
                            // handleTrialWillEnd($subscription);
                            break;
                        case 'customer.subscription.created':
                            $subscription = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\Subscription
                            // Occurs whenever a customer is signed up for a new plan.

                            $priceId = $subscription->items->data->price->id;
                        
                            if ($priceId == $price_selflearner_monthly || $priceId == $price_selflearner_yearly){
                                $current_user->set_role('self_learner');
                            }
                            
                           
                            break;
                        case 'customer.subscription.deleted':
                            $subscription = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\Subscription
                            // Occurs whenever a customer's subscription ends.
                            
                            break;
                        case 'customer.subscription.updated':
                            $subscription = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\Subscription
                            // Occurs whenever a subscription changes (e.g., switching from one plan to another, or changing the status from trial to active).
                            
                            break;
                        default:
                            // Unexpected event type
                            echo 'Received unknown event type';
                    }    

                } catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
                // Invalid payload
                echo '⚠️  Webhook error while parsing basic request.';
                http_response_code(400);
                exit();
                }
            }    
        }    
    }
}
```

I don't even know how to debug this code. I tried to inspect the value of some variables writing them in a file, but the file is always empty. It's as if nothing inside the *Case 'customer.subscription.crated'* gets executed.

I used this code to write in an errors.txt file:

```
$text = "PRICE ID: " . $priceId;
$file = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/errors.txt'; 
$open = fopen( $file, "a" ); 
$write = fputs( $open, $text); 
fclose( $open );
```

I hope someone can figure out why my code isn't working. Thanks so much!

Comment: First I would verify that there is a `$current_user`.  Webhooks are intended for async flows so there is no certainty the user is still on session.  Second, why are you making a 2nd API call to retrieve the event? The entire thing is in the API request.
Last, try logging the event type _before_ the switch statement to see what is being returned.

Comment: Thanks so much @RyanM. I tried logging the event type before the switch statement as you suggested by writing into a file, but the file didn't even get created. It's as if the function stripe_webhook() doesn't get called at all, which is not possible because the subscription is created. I also retrieved the current user using the email of the Stripe 'Customer' object and tried to update his role, but nothing happens. Still not working.

Comment: Hmmmm... Is there a way to stream out the logs?  Like using `echo`?  If so I'd start with `echo "Stripe Webhook function called` right at the very top, just to make sure your function is getting called.  Also check delivery status of these events in your Stripe Dashboard (https://dashboard.stripe.com/events).  Click on an event and check Webhook attempts/

Comment: Thanks @RyanM! I've finally found a solution. Since `echo` wouldn't work, I've used an `error_log($event->type, 1, "myemail@gmail.com");` to receive an email after each Stripe Checkout session and I realized the function wasn't getting called at all. So I placed it in a separate php file, I removed the function `stripe_webhook()` and the `if(isset($_GET['webhook-listener'])` part and in the Stripe  Dashboard I set the path so this php file as the Endpoint. It worked. I started receiving emails with the content of variables and I was able to debug the code. Now everything works perfectly.

Comment: Hooray!  I'm glad you got it working.